# Peculiar results while comparing Parallel.ForEach with foreach

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, foreach, parallel.foreach

I have been trying to optimize the performance of my WPF application where almost **40K contacts** would be downloaded from the server and the complete hierarchical tree will be created in the application. The user can only search from the tree in the view. The existing code uses lots of **foreach** loops and that takes lots of time (alone 5-6 seconds for creating the view); so I thought of modifying the code and first thing I did was to use to **Paralle.ForEach** to replace **foreach** loop. I created a very very sample application to test the difference between the two.

**Parallel.ForEach**

```
      Parallel.ForEach(lstUsers, item =>
      {
          Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
      });
```

**Normal foreach**

```
      foreach (var item in lstUsers)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
      }
```

I ran the application against 1000 contacts and to my surprise the following were the results:

**Parallel.ForEach** -> 210 milliseconds

**foreach** - > 104 milliseconds

I thought **Parallel.ForEach** should take much less time than the **foreach** loop but I am seeing just opposite. Looks like I was totally wrong.

Comment: I suspect most of your time is spent calling `Console.WriteLine`. Is that what you actually care about?

Comment: @JonSkeet - No I don't care about that. It was just for demo purpose. I just deleted the Console.WriteLine and the time elapsed with both **foreach** and **Parallel.ForEach** is 34 ms and 36 ms respectively.  In all scenarios **foreach** is clearly outperforming **Parallel.ForEach**.

Comment: When you're down to that small a timing though, you've potentially got quite a lot of overhead for task creation and coordination compared with the real work. Is your real "work per item" that short? Basically, it's unclear whether this is really a representative test.

Comment: Please forget about the application. I shouldn't have put that background there. My question is only related to my sample code attached to question. Simple console application I have created to compare the performance of two methods. So, the question is why **Parallel.ForEach** is taking more time than the **foreach** loop.

Comment: For the example you've given, I suspect that `Console` access is synchronized so you've got all the overhead of task coordination, but still with the bulk of the time with tasks waiting for console access. Without the `Console.WriteLine`, I suspect the overhead of task coordination is more than the benefit of running multi-threaded. If you put something in your loop which a) is genuinely parallel and b) takes a more significant amount of time per iteration, I'm sure you'll see the parallel version outpace the foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

you are demonstrating that this algorithm (Console.Writeline) is not a good candidate for parallelization. The overhead (which is not trivial) of running it on multiple threads is not won back by time saved by running in parallel

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you download and read the free book by Microsoft "[Patterns for Parallel Programming](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222)". What you are doing is a example they cover in the "Anti-patterns" section (patterns people tend to do but are bad)

> ### VERY SMALL LOOP BODIES
>
> As previously mentioned, the `Parallel` class is implemented in a
>   manner so as to provide for quality load balancing while incurring as
>   little overhead as possible. There is still overhead, though. The
>   overhead incurred by `Parallel.For` is largely centered around two
>   costs:
>
> 1. **Delegate invocations**. If you squint at previous examples of `Parallel.For`, a call to `Parallel.For` looks a lot like a C# for
>      loop or a Visual Basic For loop. Don’t be fooled: it’s still a method
>      call. One consequence of this is that the “body” of the `Parallel.For`
>      “loop” is supplied to the method call as a delegate. Invoking a
>      delegate incurs approximately the same amount of cost as a virtual
>      method call.
> 2. **Synchronization between threads for load balancing**. While these costs are minimized as much as possible, any amount of load
>      balancing will incur some cost, and the more load balancing employed,
>      the more synchronization is necessary.
>
> For medium to large loop bodies, these costs are largely negligible.
>   But as the size of the loop’s body decreases, the overheads become
>   more noticeable. And for very small bodies, the loop can be completely
>   dominated by this overhead’s cost. To support parallelization of very
>   small loop bodies requires addressing both #1 and #2 above.
>
> One pattern for this involves chunking the input into ranges, and then
>   instead of replacing a sequential loop with a parallel loop, wrapping
>   the sequential loop with a parallel loop.
>
> The `System.Concurrent.Collections.Partitioner` class provides a
>   `Create` method overload that accepts an integral range and returns an
>   `OrderablePartitioner<Tuple<Int32,Int32>>` (a variant for `Int64`
>   instead of `Int32` is also available):
>
> ```
> public static OrderablePartitioner<Tuple<long, long>> Create(
>     long fromInclusive, long toExclusive);
> ```
>
> Overloads of `Parallel.ForEach` accept instances of `Partitioner<T>`
>   and `OrderablePartitioner<T>` as sources, allowing you to pass the
>   result of a call to `Partitioner.Create` into a call to
>   `Parallel.ForEach`. For now, think of both `Partitioner<T>` and
>   `OrderablePartitioner<T>` as an `IEnumerable<T>`.
>
> The `Tuple<Int32,Int32>`represents a range from an inclusive value to
>   an exclusive value. Consider the following sequential loop:
>
> ```
> for (int i = from; i < to; i++)
> {
>     // ... Process i.
> }
> ```
>
> We could use a `Parallel.For` to parallelize it as follows:
>
> ```
> Parallel.For(from, to, i =>
> {
>     // ... Process i.
> });
> ```
>
> Or, we could use `Parallel.ForEach` with a call to
>   `Partitioner.Create`, wrapping a sequential loop over the range
>   provided in the `Tuple<Int32, Int32>`, where the `inclusiveLowerBound`
>   is represented by the tuple’s `Item1` and where the
>   `exclusiveUpperBound` is represented by the tuple’s `Item2`:
>
> ```
> Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(from, to), range =>
> {
>     for (int i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++)
>     {
>         // ... process i
>     }
> });
> ```
>
> While more complex, this affords us the ability to process very small
>   loop bodies by eschewing some of the aforementioned costs. Rather than
>   invoking a delegate for each body invocation, we’re now amortizing the
>   cost of the delegate invocation across all elements in the chunked
>   range. Additionally, as far as the parallel loop is concerned, there
>   are only a few elements to be processed: each range, rather than each
>   index. This implicitly decreases the cost of synchronization because
>   there are fewer elements to load-balance.
>
> While `Parallel.For` should be considered the best option for
>   parallelizing for loops, if performance measurements show that
>   speedups are not being achieved or that they’re smaller than expected,
>   you can try an approach like the one shown using `Parallel.ForEach` in
>   conjunction with `Partitioner.Create`.

Also I consider writing to `Console` to be a form of I/O, so I also would recommend reading the section in anti-patterns on "PARALLEL LOOPS FOR I/O-BOUND WORKLOADS IN SCALABLE APPLICATIONS"